# ASP.NET dotnet -ef database update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sqlite

Im following a tutorial on adding individual authentication in ASP.NET via the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=netcore-cli

In part of the tutorial it says to run database migrations using the following CLI:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Im trying to run this code in terminal but I can't seem to make it work as the command cannot find the database. The dotnet documentation for this command isn't very helpful so I'm wondering if someone could explain how this command works/how to run it on my Visual Studio WebApp project with a database called "app.db".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try specifying the context in the command like so?

```
dotnet ef database update -c MyDbContextName -e Development
```

I quite frequently run EF database migrations using the Package Manager Console rather than the CLI - so I'm not 100% familiar with it.

Each time I've had an error it's either because I was running the command without selecting the correct project first (where the project had only one context defined), or because there were multiple contexts available and it should be specified in the command which context I'm running the command against.

Comment: This seems like it would work, however turns out the problem is with the installation of dotnet rather than my original command.

Comment: It seem like after 20+ years of designing databases that Microsoft would have made it all automatic this kind of stuff.  Instead it has become more complex and more difficult to set up.  Even the setup help articles aren't any good at all.  If they were it would be very easy to setup a complete database with 1 click after making a unique selection from a list that made it completely obvious how and why it whatever is being done.  Sorry but it  definitely has not gotten any better over  time.